# How do you convert the users input into asterisks with a do while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have just recently started with Java and I am pretty bad. Im really stressing out. I need to figure out how to convert the users input between one and ten into asterisks using the `do-while` loop. I would a appreciate it A LOT if you could show me how to do this.

```
System.out.println( "Enter number between one and ten: " );
```

example: `input = 7`

expected output: `*******`

if number is not between 1 and ten display "try again" and ask again

```
public class JavaApplication12  {

/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Enter number between one and ten: " );
    int count = in.nextInt();

    int counter = 0;

    if (count<1||count>10) {
        System.out.println("Try again");
        count = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("*");
        counter++;
    }else{ 

       do {
          System.out.print("*");
          counter++;
       } while (counter < count);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please show us your attempts/code and explain how they have failed. If you haven't written anything, what have you been talking about in class that would be applicable to this problem. You know you need to write a `do-while` loop? Where are you stuck?

Comment: That is not true. Please post your code. Showing any attempt is better than nothing at all

Comment: That's not a problem, better a bad one that none.

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52863900/edit) your question and add that code directly into the question. This way it's more readable.

Comment: @lucky You don't need a nested `for` loop. `for(int i = 0; i < how_many; i++) {//print *}`

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. you need to use variable something like `counter` here and then loop until print all stars. the most important thing is `do while` run at least one time so you need to initialize `counter` to zero to work. instead you can start from 1 and change condition to `while (counter <= count)`.
I hope this is what you want:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( "Enter number between one and ten: " );
        int count = in.nextInt();
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            System.out.print("*");
            counter++;
        } while (counter < count);
    }
```

Comment: @lucky BTW, you're attempt was not that bad as you said. You could have been used your code with some tweaks instead of this one ;)

Comment: @GBlodgett I just accept a edit and `in.close` added because of that. I remove it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove extra lines in your `if` block . your code is fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication12 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( "Enter number between one and ten: " );
    int count = in.nextInt();
    int counter = 0;
    if (count<1||count>10) {
      System.out.println("Try again");
    }else{

      do {
        System.out.print("*");
        counter++;
      } while (counter < count);
    }
  }
}
```